# Show only one cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to hide the other cell which has no data,because I fill up the cell as user takes a picture.

For example

This is the table view cell,as the user takes the photo the cell should built up basically showing the covered cells.

```
-------------------                                     1)------------------
                           hiding the cell
-------------------      -------------------->            -------------------

-------------------
```

when user takes the photo the table view on the left hand side should look like on the right hand side.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.thumbnails = image;



   [self.imageView setImage:image];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.imagePickerController = nil;

    [self.view addSubview:tableViewCell];
 }  




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == Nil){

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIImage *thumbnail = self.thumbnails;
    cell.photoInfoLabel.text = @"New";
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = thumbnail;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why not just insert a new cell once the user has taken an image?

Comment: How do I insert one cell at a time??

Answer (score 0):

You can force the tableview to setup it's cells by calling

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

This causes the tableViews delegate methods to be invoked:

```
// how many rows (or cells) are there
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// create row/cell (or dequeue a reusable row/cell), set contents the row/cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can implement this methods in your viewController to control the number of cells and their content.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new cell

```
-(void)imageCaptured
{
   // NSMutableArray
   [self.aTableContent addObject:@"Some Object"];

   // Table View
   [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
   [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   [self.aTableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Really am not getting.I have updated my question and also am use overlay for my camera interface.

Comment: Take [self.view addSubview:tableViewCell]; out and replace with the code I have added above.

Comment: I got this error Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]